# Appropriate way to deal with/report spammers?

Tags: support

See this user:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/16363/remi

5 answers, all consisting of nothing more than links to the user's own commercial Plugins.

I flagged one as spam, and the account was temporarily suspended (thanks @EAMann!)

To clear out the cruft, I flagged the rest of his posts, as well.

My question: **is this the right approach**? Is there another way to report a **user**, or do we simply flag inappropriate content when we see it? The reason I ask is because, while flagging 5 or 6 questions is easy enough, that process doesn't really scale; whereas the ability to report a user (and deal with user content en masse) might be easier on the mods.

So, that's it; just looking for proper direction. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time you flag the user, it puts a permanent flag indicator on their profile.  As more and more people flag the user, that indicator increments upwards to let the moderators know there's a problem.

We try to keep close tabs on users flagged repeatedly and will take action if necessary.  In the case of this particular user, you weren't the only one letting us know there was a problem :-)

Comment: Good to know. :) So, moral of the story: keep using the flag link?

Comment: Yep. That's the best way to let the mod team know something is going on and it helps us keep track of how frequently bad things happen.